# Folder permission on Magento2

Tags: magento2

First of all: I'm new to Linux and web dev. I was a Dynamics NAV dev, so this whole things is totally new to me. I've been thrown to the deep end, so I'm trying to learn as much as

I installed Magento2 using Composer, and I can run bin/magento.

But, I can't run Magento on my browser. Running localhost just gives me white page. I can create a `HelloWorld.php` on the same folder and run it no problem though. I have setup the `.htaccess` and the config in apache2 folder.

I changed the permission to the whole `/var/www/html` folder to www-data and now I can see Magento setup page. But now I can't run `bin/magento`, because the permission is now on www-data.

Question:

- Who is supposed to be the owner for the /var/www/html folder? I'm
  supposed it's www-data?
- What's the correct setup here? Should I just put myself as part of the www-data?

Comment: www-data Owner will be working fine,

Comment: The problem is that your apache is running with www-data user, and you php CLI is running with another user (your user probally), set all the permissions to www-data user, and runs your CLI comands with www-data user to.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for Giving a Folder Permission Everytime Issue.

Open this file with sudo user

```
/etc/apache2/envvars
```

and replace www-data with your system username
for example:

> export APACHE_RUN_USER=**yoursystemuser**
>
> export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=**yoursystemuser**

line # 16-17

Save file and Run

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

and **restart apache** after that you don't need to give permission every time.

Enjoy Coding.... :)

Comment: This is a very bad idea to run apache at the system level user.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set folder permission to that listed below where you have installed:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data magento
```

this solved my problem when installing Magento.